# swift how to append a parse number column into an array

Tags: arrays, xcode, swift

I have a column in parse which stores numbers. I have been trying to append the numbers to an array like this:

```
var likes = [Int]()

getPostsQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (posts, error) -> Void in

        if let posts = posts {

            self.likes.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

            for post in posts {

                self.likes.append((post["likes"] as? Int)!)
            }
        }
    }
```

but it does not work and I'm getting this error

[image]

I have been looking around for the right way to append numbers but no luck. I tried NSNumber too but still does not work. Please help thanks!

Comment: what's the error message ? are you sure there's a value in post["likes"] ?

Comment: Try to change   - self.likes.append((post["likes"] as? Int)!) - to if let value = post["likes"] as? Int{
 self.likes.append(values)
}